# CERT FOE Fuzzing Framework documentation

Tags: tools, fuzzing, documents

So I read another post here about fuzzing local standalone applications. I have understood how to exploit basic buffer overflow vulnerabilities in standalone applications and am now looking on how to find such vulnerabilities.

I downloaded the [CERT FOE framework](https://www.cert.org/blogs/certcc/2012/07/cert_failure_observation_engin_1.html), but found very little documentation on it. In fact, the only thing I found was [one video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kraczmgAmgo).

Could someone provide sources of documentation/videos for the CERT FOE fuzzing framework?

Comment: "Many options can be specified in the configuration file. See the included README.txt and configs\examples for more information." -- It doesn't look they they wrote documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Lets not [shave a yak](http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2005/03/dont_shave_that.html). It sounds as though you want to understand and get into fuzzing.

[Sulley](https://github.com/OpenRCE/sulley) and [Peach](http://www.peachfuzzer.com/) are fuzzers that have extensive capabilities that should help you. Also, writing your [own](https://www.exploit-db.com/papers/12965/) fuzzer should help understanding the actual fuzzing process.

[Here](http://www.fuzzing.org/) is a resource for a bunch of different fuzzers.

Ultimately, common sense aids in the fuzzing process. If the binary accepts files (and you're fuzzing file formats) on linux, having your testcases generated on the fly on a ramdisk helps. On windows you need specialized ramdisk [software](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/12-ram-disk-software-benchmarked-for-fastest-read-and-write-speed/), of which SoftPerfect Ramdisk looks the be the most [efficient](https://www.softperfect.com/products/ramdisk/). Ramdisks minimize disk I/O, so it speeds up fuzzing and lessens the wear&tear to your HDD.

Also, you need to take into account what the specification says, then disregard it with the utmost abandon! [010Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) helps as it is a hexeditor that has can parse known file formats.

For instance, you need to take into account your platform's integer limits, whether [windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx) or [linux](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm). Also, most source code has its own defined integer limits, so where does it differ from the platform (u)int limits? Also, some software parses strings. Does it accept null bytes? In which situations? If you're black-box fuzzing (no source available) what happens if you pass a (u)int that is equal to the platform limits defined?

If you start fuzzing from scratch (like I did) you'll be that much closer to more effectively finding bugs than your peers.

Good luck